# DropboxSDK.framework file not found after relaunching Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, dropbox

I am using the `DropboxSDK.framework` in a project of mine. 
I have everything setup and working fine. However, every time I quite Xcode and open it again at a later point I get the error below:[image]

Which is weird because I can see that the framework is in the project and nothing (that I know of) has changed since the last time I had the project open and working.

The way I make the error go away is to:

1. Right click on the `DropboxSDK.framework` in my project --> `Delete --> Remove Reference.`
2. In my project's **Build Settings** under **Search Paths** I remove the path that is under **Framework Search Paths** (the highlighted selection in the image below). [image]
3. Then I clean my project `SHIFT + CMD + K`
4. Lastly, I click `File --> Add files to my project`, navigate to the `DropboxSDK.framework` file which I previously removed reference to and add it back to my project.
5. Then I build my project again and the error goes away and will remain gone until I quite Xcode and open it again.

Has anyone else ever encountered this happening and fixed it?

Or have any suggestions I could try to fix it? I'm using Xcode V5.1.1

Let me know if there's anything I can clarify. Thank you!

Comment: are you using dynamic path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a random thought sparked by Indrajeet's answer that solved my problem.

When a new project is created in Xcode a project folder is created. In that folder there is another folder with the same name as your project, a `.xcodeproj` file with your project's name and a yourProjectNameTests folder.

Visually like this.

```
 Application_Name --> Application_Name
                      Application_Name.xcodeproj
                      Application_NameTests
```

When I was having the error I described above the `DropboxSDK.framework` and it's accompanying files were stored here in this folder:
[image]

After removing all references to the `DropboxSDK.framework` in my project I decided to move the `DropboxSDK.framwork` and it's accompanying files one folder level up to the main Application_Name folder here:
[image]

Once I did this, I clicked `File --> Add files to my project`, navigated to the `DropboxSDK.framework` file, now one folder level up and added it to my project.

After building no error was thrown. I restarted Xcode and tried again to make sure; still no error. Rebooted my computer to be truly sure... still no error!

Answer (score 0):

$(SRCROOT)/Application_Folder

- Application_Folder is the name of the folder where your whole code other resources resides
- Insert above line in Header Search Paths

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't change anything. Your suggestion did get me thinking about which folders I had the DropboxSDK files stored in and maybe that had something to do with it. I ended up solving my problem by moving the Dropbox files up a folder level. I added it as an answer so you can see what I did. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would you be able to shed anymore light on why you suggested the above? I still feel like the way I fixed the problem was pretty hackie and I'm most sure why it worked. 
Before I tried adding your above suggestion the Header Search Paths read $(inherited) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
And using yours it reads, $(SRCROOT)/Application_Folder 
Why would I use one or another? Using either doesn't seem to change anything even when I have blank there it doesn't seem to have an effect. Or is this a question for another place? Thanks!

Comment: Mostly this error rises when you copy project from one pc to another or on another folder. When you copy project its path is also copy as it is and the problem arises if path is static. When I saw your problem this thing comes in my mind and suggest this solution. This is the dynamic path, once you give this then you can copy your project anywhere it never gives you this type of error.

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense.That's for the clarification and help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the sane problem and just found the answer by chance!
It happens when you create your project name with SPACES between the letters. Somehow it makes XCode crazy when searching for the frameworks.

So if want to create a project called "This is My Project Name", call it "This_is_My_Project_Name" and the frameworks will be found every time. It worked with me.